# How do I change my image background to red

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image with gray ROI and black background, which I got from imfreehand function. I want to change that black background to red. Following is link for image.

[image: imfreehand image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this.

1. Set black to "NaN" then do: set(gca,'Color','r')
2. Use "find" to get indices of black pixels and set colors in respective planes to [1,0,0] for red, blue, green planes of jpg respectively.

I'm sure there are others, but these are the first two that come to mind.